# "RuntimeError: Invalid Pointer" error when trying to export raster

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-10.3, idle

I am trying to create an NDVI image from a Landsat 8 tif image, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to export the NDVI image without getting the "Invalid Pointer" error. I'm working with IDLE (ArcGIS 10.3) as my IDE. Here's my code:

```
#Import modules
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *

env.workspace = "C:\\rasterFolder"
env.overwriteOutput = True

#Check out extension
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

#Define raster
inRaster = arcpy.Raster("LANDSAT8_3244532.tif")

#Define bands
red = arcpy.Raster("LANDSAT8_3244532.tif\\Band_4")
nir = arcpy.Raster("LANDSAT8_3244532.tif\\Band_5")

#Compute NDVI
outRaster = ((nir - red) / (nir + red))

### Save raster: ERROR OCCURS HERE ###
outRaster.save("C:\\Users\\asdf\\downloads\\rasterFolder")
```

How can I export the raster (using IDLE) into a desired folder? Am I using the right method for this?

Comment: Please post the entire error stack.

Comment: Have you tried including a file name in the save path?  Eg:  `outRaster.save("C:\\Users\\asdf\\downloads\\rasterFolder\\ndvi")`

Comment: A file suffix is needed as well to get a GeoTIFF output.

Comment: @Son of a Beach Thank you, I updated the folder to the file path described, as well as put a ".tif" suffix, and it worked great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Vince As mentioned above, I included the suffix, and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the comments, I put a ".tif" suffix on the end of the save path, and it worked.